# How do I prevent PowerShell from adding exception data to $error

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0, powershell-6.0

I am invoking a lot of REST calls in a function.
I know that some of them will fail, but that is expected.

My question is:

How do I prevent powershell from adding entries to the global `$error` variable?

foreach:

```
$oldErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = "Ignore"
try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -ea Ignore
} catch {
    Write-Verbose "$_"
} finally {
    $ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorActionPreference
}
```

---

`$error` variable after invoking:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't `$Error` store all the errors that have occurred in a Powershell session? It would be much safer to user `$error[0]` to look at the latest error, then slowly move up the array if required.

Comment: Why would you even want to? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am creating a set of core modules, that in themselves must be non-leaking to $global:error.

Comment: The exception is "expected" - and is therefore not an error. I do not like that an exceptional state that my code have "accepted", still leaks to global:error.
This creates an overloaded $error, that again then cannot be used for tracking and finding real "errors"

Answer (score 2):

`Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet always fails with *terminating error*, which can't be `Ignored` — it will always end up inside `$Error` list.

You can clear it: `$Error.Clear()`

Comment: Source for this?

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen about Invoke-RestMethod always throwing terminating errors can be deduced from here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/WebRequestPSCmdlet.Common.cs#L1444

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen PowerShell error handling and what and when goes into $Error variable explained (in length) here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583